# MSCK REPAIR TABLE table name taking long time

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` table name on a hive table which contains more than 28K partitions and we'll be receiving a partition for every 10 mins.

When we run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` on this table every 10 mins it's taking a lot if time

Could someone suggest why it's taking more time? (i.e more than 5-10 mins)

Thanks in advance.

Hive version: 1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

This is a very bad practice.
Whether a directory is already mapped to a partition or not, `MSCK REPAIR` still needs to get the list of all directories as well as the list of all partitions and compare them.
Instead, you should use `alter table ... add partition ...` to add a partition every time you add a directory.

Comment: Thanks @Dudu Markovitz for quick reply , but we're ingesting data to HDFS via Flume and built an external table on top of the directory where we place the data from Flume

Comment: @Naga, I don't get the issue. While you creating the directory can't you also add the partition or at least store the name of the directory somewhere and add it later as a partition?