# msck repair table command runs slow in AWS Athena after deleting few hundred partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I've deleted around 700 partitions data (s3) from AWS Athena table.

To update partitions information, I'm running `MSCK Repair table` command, but its taking **more than 7 minutes** to run.

Before deleting 700 partitions, `msck repair table` command used to take **less than 15 seconds** to run.

I referred to:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-msck-repair-table-time-out/
2. [AWS Athena MSCK REPAIR TABLE takes too long for a small dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107866/aws-athena-msck-repair-table-takes-too-long-for-a-small-dataset)
3. [MSCK REPAIR TABLE table name taking long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599976/msck-repair-table-table-name-taking-long-time)

Followed steps, but of no avail.

Anyone faced this before and solved?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a work around!

*Caution: Use below method only if you know the consequences of dropping and recreating table in your scenario.*

Drop and recreate table solved the issue.

Steps I followed to make "msck repair table" command to ***behave*** properly:

1. Copy DDL of the Athena table in an editor
2. Drop Athena table
3. Recreate Athena table using DDL from step 1.
4. Run `msck repair table` command.